# JSON and WCF Web service

Tags: java, wcf, json, rest

First off, this is my first post on stack overflow. I have been visiting this site for a long time and have never really asked a question because of the abundant resources already available. One problem I am having seems to be a little difficult to find correct information on. If my post is not appropriate or there is anything I should consider in the future before posting please let me know.

I am working on a WCF interface for a somewhat simple windows service. The idea is that it will have two endpoints available, a TCP endpoint and an HTTP endpoint using JSON.

I have the WCF interface complete so I can test it by navigating to the proper URL, and everything seems great. The next step which is a little difficult for me is the java client side of things. I need to create a java class to interface with the WCF service. I could use a URLConnection to invoke a GET, but how would I go about this with a POST? Below is an example of the service contract.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPenguinWCF_JSON
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "listsigns/")]
    string[] ListSigns();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "stopserver/")]
    bool StopServer();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "sendmessage")]
    bool SendMessage(string signName, string zone, string text, bool scroll);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Apache HttpClient library](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to write a client.

Comment: Would this require the client to run on a computer with apache installed? What if the java modules were to be used on another system or device such as a windows box with IIS and no apache, or a blackberry?

Comment: No, it doesn't require the Apache web server. The "Apache" in the name just means that it's a project under the Apache Software Foundation. All that is required is a JRE, and some supporting libraries that are included in the distribution. There are a number of easy to follow tutorials on the Web for using HttpClient.

Comment: Opening a connection seems to be easy enough. There is a little more to it to get it to work properly and receive a consumable JSON response. I will post my results. The answer only has a very basic part of what is required. Opening a connection to the web service is kind of known. The trick was in the content-type and accept request properties. Thank you for the answer, I do appreciate your input.